# \ifthenelse statement inside includemedia options

Tags: conditionals, media9, ifthenelse

I try to enable / disable some options for my 3D view with \ifthenelse.

```
\documentclass[fontsize=12pt,paper=a4]{scrbook}
\usepackage{media9}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{ifthen}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[H]
\scalebox{.5}{
\includemedia[
width=1\linewidth,
height=0.56\linewidth,
3Daac=60.000001669652114,
3Droll=-37.47084467351308,
3Dc2c=-0.012050606310367584 -0.0156868789345026 0.9998043775558472,
3Dcoo=38.000003814697266 21.499998092651367 -0.7999938726425171,
3Droo=59.6515823704357,
{\ifthenelse{\boolean{myDraft}}{3Dmenu}{}}]
{\includegraphics{./_Images/Transceiver.png}}{./_CAD/TransceiverMC.prc}}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

But I got the error: **Unknown option \ifthenelse**

How can I enable / disable the 3Dmenu option depending on the *myDraft* variable? Is there a possibility to set the option outside of the \includemedia call?

EDIT:

I found [this](http://Using%20%5Cifthenelse%20inside%20an%20option) question, but I can not handle it in my case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As too long for a comment: The problem probably is that `\ifthenelse` is not fully expandable.

What might work is to execute the test, storing the new option in a macro, and then adding the option in an `\edef`:

```
\def\myopt{}
\ifthenelse{\boolean{myDraft}}{\def\myopt{3Dmenu}}{}
\edef\temp{\unexpanded{
    \includemedia[
    width=1\linewidth,
    height=0.56\linewidth,
    3Daac=60.000001669652114,
    3Droll=-37.47084467351308,
    3Dc2c=-0.012050606310367584 -0.0156868789345026 0.9998043775558472,
    3Dcoo=38.000003814697266 21.499998092651367 -0.7999938726425171,
    3Droo=59.6515823704357,}
    \myopt]
}\temp{\includegraphics{./_Images/Transceiver.png}}{./_CAD/TransceiverMC.prc}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply but it doesn't work 'Paragraph ended before includemedia was complete'. After setting '\expandafter\temp\expandafter{\myopt}' two bracket layers up, it compiles but doesn't create an output.

Comment: Perfect! Now it works like expected!